# Can $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} e^{-x} dx$ be integrated?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, numerical-methods, singularity

I have an integral with a singularity at $x = 0$.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} e^{-x} dx$$

It's not a removable singularity so is it possible to perform the integration? For example could some complex analysis technique or some numeric method be used to integrate this? Or is it simply not integrable?

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x}$ diverges, and $e^{-x} > 1-x$

Comment: @user1952009 $e^{-x} > \frac1e$ is an even simpler estimate, but yes.

Answer (score 3):

This is not integrable because $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}e^{-x} dx  > \frac{1}{e}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = \infty$

Comment: You missed the $dx$.

Comment: Sorry I edited it... terrible habit i have with one dimensional integrals.